# Primary key referenced as a multivalued foreign key?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I was wondering if I could pass the primary key from one table to another and make it multivalued in THAT table to then reference it as a composite foreign key in another table.

Here's the situation: I have a `Services` table, every service has a `serviceCode` primary key and a `serviceFee` assigned to it.

Services are used in appointments, up to 5 services for an appointment. Appointments generate invoices which also need the service fee to calculate the total fee.

So far my schema is:

- `service` (serviceCode, description, serviceFee)
- `appointment` ([appDate, clientNo, serviceCode]PK, roomNo)
- `invoice` (invNo, invDate, totalFee, comment, status, [appDate, clientNo, serviceCode]FK)

Would that even be possible? Though I suppose I'd need to add `serviceFee` as part of services primary key so I can pass it to invoice since I'm not sure if I can separately pass `serviceFee` to invoice alone.

Another solution I'm thinking about in my head is turning appointment into a complex relationship since appDate is its only attribute, everything else is being reference from other tables. Then I'd just pass everything off to invoice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about SQLLITE. In SQL Server, you could do it like.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[service](


    [serviceCode] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [description] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [servicefee] [float] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK__service__3213E83F014935CB] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [serviceCode] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[appointment](
   [appDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [clientNo] [int] NOT NULL,
    [serviceCode] [int] NOT NULL,
    [roomNo] [float] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK__appointment__3213E83F014935CB] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [serviceCode] ASC,
    [appDate] ASC,
    [clientNo] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[invoice](
(invNo, invDate, totalFee, comment, status, [appDate, clientNo, serviceCode]FK
    [invDate] [datetime] not NULL,
    [invNo] [int] not NULL,
    [totalFee] [float] not null,
    [comment] [varchar](max),
    [status] [varchar](max),
    [appDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [clientNo] [int] NULL,
    [serviceCode] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [FK_appointment_service]    Script Date: 04/13/2016 10:43:41 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[appointment]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_appointment_service] FOREIGN KEY([serviceCode])
REFERENCES [dbo].[service] ([serviceCode])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[appointment] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_appointment_service]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [FK_invoice_appointment]    Script Date: 04/13/2016 10:43:41 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[invoice]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_invoice_appointment] FOREIGN KEY([serviceCode], [appDate], [clientNo])
REFERENCES [dbo].[appointment] ([serviceCode], [appDate], [clientNo])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[invoice] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_invoice_appointment]
GO
```

Comment: Yeah, my best bet would be to create additional tables to deal with the problem. It is the only way for me to deal with multivalued attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have composite-key as PK and FK.

Go to [SQLLITE Foreign Key Definition](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html) and look for "Composite Foreign Key Constraints"

**BUT, the first thing you need to consider: There is a big issue in your tables design. You should avoid composite PK.**

**You should to use one single field as PK, it might be IDENTIY, GUID or anything else. For your case, you'll be in a big trouble with this design**

Comment: Thank you for the link. The part about needing to create unique indexes in order to reference a foreign key that isn't part of the primary key was very helpful. I'm actually thinking too far ahead at the moment right now as I'm only producing a conceptual model now and will be going further with a logical model later.